# SQL Server Training Books and Videos

Tags: sql-server

I am just starting out in the world of SQL Server Database/Server administration, Due to a unexpected workload..

Can anyone suggest good, free training books or free training videos.

Which cover Profiler, Perfmon and other essential aspects of administering a server

I have read the book by How to Become an Exceptional DBA by Brad M McGehee but that was more about a DBA as a person. (I do fit the profile but not the wage at the moment) 10 years. I will be there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best documentation is the SQL Books online
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx

Videos covering backup basics and a few other tips/tricks are here
http://www.sqlservervideos.com

Comment: If you're looking for free books on Profiler, I'd recommend Brad McGehee's excellent book here: http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/book-store/
I also outlined a bunch of free resources here: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/sql-server/free-sql-server-resources-developers-136065/

But that list didn't include many of the great blogs and other sites listed in a similar question on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103221/good-sql-server-courses-and-or-books/4103358#4103358

Comment: SQL Server Statistics by Holger Schmeling is a great book which gave me a good understanding of this subject and is worth reading. Even if you are just starting out.

Answer (score 2):

www.sqlservercentral.com is a great resource as well.  Lot's of good articles and blog entries around features and tasks.

There is a really good Stairway series on SQL Server that covers the profiler and other admin tasks.

www.sqlcat.com is good for whitepapers

Also look into www.sqlpass.org, which is the Professional Association for SQL Server, and sswug.org which also has lots of articles and features.  SQL PASS has regional chapters that meet and present regularly.  The one for my area puts those sessions up on the web as archives which is very helpful.

I'm sure there are other ways to find books "that fell off a back of a truck" in digital form around the internet as well.